# GiveFeedback event not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, events, drag-and-drop

I can't get `GiveFeedback` event firing with my `ListView` control.
The code below is just for this testing, and it's updating text labels from events, just to see what events are firing and when. `label1` updates when dragging an item, and `label3` when item drops. But why `label2` never gets updated? What am I missing?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    listView1.ItemDrag += new ItemDragEventHandler(listView1_ItemDrag);
    listView1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(listView1_DragDrop);
    listView1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(listView1_DragEnter);
    listView1.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(listView1_DragOver);
    listView1.GiveFeedback += new GiveFeedbackEventHandler(listView1_GiveFeedback);
}

private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.All);
}

private void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void listView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "DragOver " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}

private void listView1_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = "GiveFeedback " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}

private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    label3.Text = "DragDrop " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.All);
```

This is where the problem started.  You are using your *form's* DoDragDrop() method.  The GiveFeedback event is fired on the drag source, unlike the other events that fire on the drop target.  So you subscribed the wrong event, it should have been this.GiveFeedback instead of listView1.GiveFeedback.  Or the more obvious fix since you seem to want to implement D+D only for the listview:

```
   listView1.DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.All);
```

Comment: Thanks! Such an easy fix, but does not come to my mind at all.